# Differential amplifier advantage in IC manufacturing

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, differential

Differential amplifier will overcome need of blocking, coupling, and bypass capacitor present in normal amplifier made from single transistor. Hence, all IC contains majorly this differential amplifier inside, as capacitor are more bulky. Can anyone explain how need of these capacitors are eliminated in differential amplifier?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a differential amplifier completely eliminates the need for all capacitors.

Differential amplifier (or any other circuit having a differential pair of transistors) requires matched transistor characteristics. Transistor hFE for example can vary from one silicon wafer to another, or even across different locations on the same wafer. Building a differential amplifier with discrete transistors, there is always some mismatch between the devices, causing offset errors. Even if you somehow obtained two transistors that were cut from the same area of the same silicon wafer, they are in different discrete packages so will be at slightly different temperatures. But integrated circuit has both of the input transistors on the same silicon wafer, in adjacent location, at the same temperature, so their hFE and other characteristics closely match. This balances manufacturing variations, reducing offset voltage error.

So it is possible for a hobbyist to build a single-ended common-emitter amplifier from discrete components: a single NPN transistor and a couple of resistors and capacitors. But it's a great deal harder to build a working op-amp from discrete components. Op-amp requires a differential pair of input transistors; look at the uA741 schematic for example. So op-amps must be built as integrated circuits.

You'll notice that even inside the uA741 there is an internal capacitor configured to reduce the gain at high frequencies; this is required to make the op-amp unity-gain stable. Some op-amps are offered without any internal frequency compensation; these "uncompensated" op-amps have higher gain but must be operated with a specified closed-loop gain (greater than 1V/V; minimum gain specified in data sheet) to avoid oscillation.

By "blocking capacitor" you mean a series capacitor used to block AC component of a signal? I don't see how that relates directly to differential amplifier. I think that's more a matter of whether the signal is processed as DC-coupled or AC-coupled. A differential signal source can be AC-coupled or DC-coupled, just like a single-ended signal source. Except a differential AC-coupled signal would require two series capacitors, one for each of its two wires.

The need for bypass capacitor is never completely eliminated. The size of the bypass capacitor will be reduced if the changes in load current |di/dt| are minimized, but practically all IC require some amount of local power supply bypass capacitor because every PCB trace and every wire has inductance.

Answer (score 0):

"Can anyone explain how need of these capacitors are eliminated in differential amplifier?"

Mostly they aren't. If you have an input signal with an AC component and a DC component, you can remove the DC with a series capacitor. You can do the same with a differential amplifier, BUT ONLY IF YOU KNOW THE VALUE OF THE DC. Generally you don't know that, so you cannot use a differential amplifier for that purpose. Worse, you generally want to amplify the AC, and the greater the gain, the more accuracy is required in knowing the DC level for a differential amp. A capacitor does it all "automatically" - within the limits imposed by its leakage currents.